Difficulty Applying Dynamic left Style in Salesforce Modal Component
I’m working on a component in Salesforce that I’m using inside a modal (popup) on a record page. I’m trying to dynamically apply the left style to this component based on its position, but I’m running into some issues.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Using getBoundingClientRect(): This method works fine on the record page, providing the correct x and y positions. However, it doesn’t seem to work correctly within the Salesforce modal.
Calculating Position with offsetParent: I’ve attempted to use offsetParent to calculate the position, but this hasn’t yielded the results I expected.
Querying the Modal Container:
I’ve tried selecting the modal container using document.querySelector('.slds-modal__container').
I’ve also tried document.getElementsByClassName('slds-modal__container').
I tried using element.closest('.slds-modal__container'), but it returned undefined.
Unfortunately, neither approach has worked in getting the correct positioning for the component.
Here’s a summary of my challenges:
The position calculation works on a regular record page but fails within the modal.
Standard methods for querying the modal container don’t seem to work.
Questions:
Has anyone experienced similar issues when trying to position elements within Salesforce modals?
Are there specific considerations or techniques for positioning elements dynamically within Salesforce modals?
Any suggestions for alternative methods or debugging tips to help resolve this issue?
I’d greatly appreciate any insights or solutions you might have!
Thanks in advance!

Is this using the lightning-modal component?

Yes, it uses a lightning-modal component to render in the UI. When I click the Quick Action button, the modal automatically opens.
